# Batch to rename files and remove the date in filename

Tags: batch-file, design-patterns, rename

I have multiple directories and subdirectories and need to remove the date part of all filenames and keep the rest of the file name.

Ex.

Input:  Dummy-Filename-V0001-01202018.txt

Output: Dummy-Filename-V0001.txt

Basically, I need to remove the "-01202018" part.

Notes:

1. It should also cover other file format like ".pdf" ".csv" and others (not sure of all file types available)
2. The date could be in different formats like DDMMYYYY, MMDDYYYY, YYYYMMDD, or other combination.
3. So far, I've seen the date only at the end part of the filenames.
4. I have files under /Sample/00AA/0001/01202018/file.txt up to /5000/ and there's also /Sample/00BB/ with sub folders.

I currently have the code below, I'm already able to loop through all the subdirectories and show files with dates, but the rename commands that I tried wont work. (see comments)

```
FOR /R "C:\Users\Dummy\Desktop\UAT\Sample\" %%G in (.) DO (
Pushd %%G
Echo now in %%G
echo before
dir
dir "*-01202018*"

REM ren *-01202018.txt *.txt
REM ren ???-01202018.txt ???.txt
REM rename 's/-01202018//' *
REM rename "*-01202018*" "*/////////*"

echo after
dir
Popd )
Echo "back home"

PAUSE
```

Comment: I question your motivation and wonder how many of those names will no longer be unique when the date stamps are removed?

Comment: All files are unique, the same file could occur in a different date folder in the directory. Oh sorry about that, the directories have date folders. /Sample/00AA/0001/01202018/file.txt

Comment: Does every file in those directories, have the same -Date postfix or are some of them undated?  Do any of them have more than one hyphen or more than one period?

Comment: Some doesn't have dates, some have dates and dates are in different formats as seen above..Those without dates does not need to be touched.

Comment: Yes, hypens, period, and underscores (I haven't notice any other special characters) may or may not appear on filenames.

Comment: Ok, so we have potentially random quantities of periods and hyphens in the set of file names?  Can we at least assume that a final hyphen followed by digits and a final period, tells us that file name needs to be truncated?

Comment: If by a final hypen and digits we could use a hypen and a date that I could enter as a parameter that would be better as there could also be hypen with some random numbers that could be mistaken for the date. If I can enter the date as parameter I'm ok with re-running it to cover all combination.

Answer (score 1):

From our discussion above, I attempted to generify this solution as much as possible:

```
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@set prompt=$G

@if "%1" equ "" goto :UsageError PrefixPattern
@if "%2" equ "" goto :UsageError Literal
@if "%3" equ "" goto :UsageError PostfixPattern

@for %%A in (%1%2%3) do @call :TruncateFileName "%%A" "%2"
@exit /b 0

:TruncateFileName
@set _name=%~1
@set _name=!_name:%~2=!
@echo Renaming %~1 =^> %_name%
@ren %1 "%_name%"
@exit /b 0

:UsageError
@echo Missing parameter: %1
@exit /b 160
```

Be sure to test this in a copy of one or more of your actual target directories.  You can test it stand-alone one directory at a time, but I would write a script to iterate over your directories and just call this script there ([lots of examples can be found here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5DIterate+directories)).

Usage: `RenameThem.cmd <prefixPattern> <literal> <postfixPattern>`

Example: RenameThem.cmd * -20180109 *.pdf

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I had dinner guests this evening. The above script took about 20 minutes to write-up and test.  It's only had a hand full of permutations, so I recommend that you test it on a copy of one or more of your data files.  You can also use it as a template for a script that would just dump the names of the files it would have changed, and what it would have changed them to, by simply replacing the `@ren` command with an `@echo` command.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! The main problem I had before seems to be on the wildcard as I needed a more specific part of the filename. I ended up putting the parts of the filename on the script for the before and after rename. Sorry I wasn't able to wait for this because it was a production issue and needed immediate resolution. I'll try this code and test if it's more dynamic and update the one in prod if they still want it. Thanks!